# How to limit API calls to a node app on AWS EC2

Tags: ajax, node.js, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a web site hosted on Namecheap and a node app on AWS EC2. The node app handles just a few api calls. The web site on Namecheap sends AJAX calls to the node app to receive confidential information. I am trying limit the access to the node app to only my website on Namecheap so that no one else can make ajax calls to the node app. How can I do that?
Thank you for your attention!

Comment: have you got any authentication setup?

Comment: The website does not require authentication. As long as the ajax calls come from the my website only, it is fine. I just dont want other people to see the source code and abuse the api call address

Answer (score 2):

There are not many options when it comes to securing your node app in this case. Because your website source code is visible to everyone, API Keys are useless as they can be read in plain text. Authentication is possible if the website prompts the user to login before handling the AJAX call to the node app.

Authentication can be implemented in a node app using express by installing basic-auth-connect and using it for your express app.

```
var basicAuth = require('basic-auth-connect');
app.use(basicAuth(username, password));
```

If you are using JQuery to make the AJAX request, adding authentication is simple. Add the `username` and `password` options to your request.

**EDIT:** As suggested by Asif, Two-Factor Authentication is probably the way to go as it provides credentials that assure no one will continue using your service for extended periods of time. However, it can be inconvenient in certain use-cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement 2 factor https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-totp or oauth2 https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2 with passport

Enabling Cors

```
 var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');

    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.send(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
};

app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use AWS built in security inbound rules to restrict calls by adding the IP your frontend is hosted on. You would edit the security group's inbound rules that is attached to your EC2 instance

Comment: Would it not already be enabled considering his frontend and backend are separate?

Comment: They are AJAX calls from a website. The inbound requests wouldn't be coming from the IP address that the frontend is hosted on. The inbound requests would be coming directly from user's browsers.